# CivicAddressResolver IsUnknown is always true even in Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is anyone succesful getting address information from CivicAddressResolver? I am testing in samsung focus.

Thanks
Ashraf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddressresolver%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> "This class is not implemented in the current release."